# ¿Cómo aumentar el valor de un elemento de una lista que esta dentro de otra lista?

Tags: python, bucle-for, condiciones, while, python-3.7

Necesito ayuda con el siguiente tema, resulta que tengo una lista con tres listas adentro:

```
lista = [[1, 2], [100, 131], [65, 81]]
#index      0         1          2
```

Adicionalmente, tengo una lista con ciertas cantidades:

```
cantidades = [10, 20]
```

Ahora bien necesito validar lo siguiente: para cada índex de lista[1] y lista[2] si esta dentro de cierto rango me reste 1 a la lista de "cantidades" según la posición de lista[0], por ejemplo para el index 0 de lista[1], es decir 100, sea mayor que 130 y para el index 0 de lista[2], es decir 65, sea mayor que 80 me reste 1 a cantidades[0], y así mismo para los demás posiciones que pueda tener lista[1] y lista[2].

Al final la lista "cantidades" debería quedar así, validando que una de las posiciones de lista[1] y lista[2] si es mayor que 130 y 80 respectivamente:

```
cantidades = [10, 19]
```

Agradezco me puedan ayudar con esto, llevo dos días intentándolo

Comment: Si no he entendido mal, ¿tienes que comprobar los elementos de las sublistas, si el primero es mayor que el segundo restar 1 a `cantidades[0]` y sin embargo si el segndo es mayor restar 1 a `cantidades[1]`? Es bastante complejo de entender.. intenta explicarlo mejor para que podamos entenderlo y ayudarte

Comment: @adrigo No, supongamos que la sublista0 son tienda 1 y 2, la sublista1, son cantidades de cierto producto en las tiendas al igual que sublista2. Ahora, en la lista "cantidades"  hay dos cantidades de productos que están disponibles para vender. Podríamos decir que para tienda1, hay 100 ítems de un producto y 65 de otro igual que para la tienda2, hay 131 ítems de producto y 81 del otro.

Comment: @adrigo Aquí donde empieza la validación, si para la tienda 1 el producto1 (100) es mayor que 130 y el producto 2 (65) es mayor que 80, me disminuya 1 en cantidades 1 (10) sino no haga nada, también para el segundo producto de las sublistas. Es por eso que en el ejemplo puse que para el producto 2 de cantidades le resta 1, porque los segundos ítems de sublistas1 y 2, si son mayores que la condición.

Comment: Vale, ahora entiendo... entonces el resultado no seria restando 1 sino 2, porque en los dos casos la cantidad del producto de la tienda 2 es mayor que el de la tienda 1, por lo que deberia quedar cantidades asi: `[10, 18]`, ¿No?